# Store Pickup Not Working for Products with Custom Options SKU

Tags: magento2, store-pickup

I am trying to use Magento's Store Pickup Module on our site but I have come across an issue. If you use custom options and assign a SKU to that option store pickup isn't available.

This is because the SKU of the product with options is different to the product that has the stock assigned ie TESTPRODUCT has stock assigned but TESTPRODUCT-OPTION1 hasn't.

I have found a workaround, by import both SKU's into the sources it will let me use the Store pickup the only problem with that is it doesn't reduce the stock for the main product

Comment: Are you asking about `Pickup shipping method` ? which exact version you are using ?

Comment: Yes, Its called In-Store Delivery in shipping methods. I am testing it on Magento version 2.4.5

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/OfflineShipping/Model/Carrier/Pickup.php#L67

Comment: As of now (till magento 2.4.5) Store pickup is not available and always return false!

Comment: I am on 2.4.5, it this issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34889 but it looks like they couldn't reproduce it

Comment: can you see shipping method for simple product ?

Comment: Yes, If I have a product with no custom options its fine, and if I import the sources/stock for the custom options it works but it doesn't reduce the stock for the main product